# How to properly synchronized 2 threads on 2 different objects in Java with wait/notify?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads, thread-synchronization

I am learning synchronization in Java. I know this is a very basic question, but I can't figure it out.

I have class which contains 2 different objects and 2 Threads.

```
class MyThreads {
    public final static Object den = new Object();
    public final static Object ada = new Object();

    public static Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread 1 den");
            System.out.println("Thread 1 ada");
        }
    };

    public static Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
              System.out.println("Thread 2 den");
              System.out.println("Thread 2 ada");
        }
    };
}
```

After execute this code:

```
MyThreads.t1.start();
MyThreads.t2.start();
```

I should get:

```
Thread 1 den
Thread 2 den
Thread 1 ada
Thread 2 ada
```

I am struggling here. I don't understand how thread 1 can awake thread 2.

```
public static Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread 1 den");
            synchronized (den) {
                try {   
                    den.notifyAll();
                    den.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

public static Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (ada){
                        ada.wait();
//                     How to awake it?
                        }
        }
    };
```

I will be thankful for any advice!

Comment: `ada.wait()` will only stop blocking, when `ada.notify()` or `ada.notifyAll()` has been called after `t2` has called `ada.wait()`. For me, the logic of the program looks broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired output where "Thread 1 den" is printed before "Thread 2 den", and "Thread 1 ada" is printed before "Thread 2 ada", you can use wait() and notifyAll() methods to synchronize the execution of the threads. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
    class MyThreads {
    public final static Object den = new Object();
    public final static Object ada = new Object();

    public static Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread 1 den");
            synchronized (den) {
                try {
                    den.wait();  // Wait until den is notified
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Thread 1 ada");
            
            synchronized (ada) {
                ada.notifyAll();  // Notify ada to wake up Thread 2
            }
        }
    };

    public static Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (den) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2 den");
            den.notifyAll();
            }

            synchronized (ada) {
                try {
                    ada.wait();  // Wait until ada is notified
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Thread 2 ada");
        }
    };
}
```

In the updated code, the t1 thread first enters a synchronized block on den and calls den.wait(). This causes t1 to wait until it is notified by another thread. Meanwhile, t2 thread is executed and it enters a synchronized block on den and calls den.notifyAll(), which wakes up the waiting t1 thread.

After t1 is awakened, it prints "Thread 1 den". Then, it enters a synchronized block on ada and calls ada.notifyAll(), which wakes up the waiting t2 thread.

Finally, t2 is awakened and it prints "Thread 2 ada".

By using wait() and notifyAll() methods along with synchronized blocks, you can control the order of execution between the threads and achieve the desired output.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps me! Wasn't really understand how to use 2 different objects, but you make it clear. Solved

Comment: As an aside: this program has the potential to deadlock. Thread `t2` can reach `den.notifyAll()` before `t1` reaches `den.wait()`. It is not sufficient to call `start()`on `t1` before calling `start()`on `t2` to prevent this problem.

Comment: @Turing85 Thank for your remark.
now my code looks like that:
`thread 1: run() {
sout("Thread 1 ada");
synchronized (ada) {
ada.notifyAll(); }
 
       
thread 2: run() {
 synchronized (ada) {
 try {
ada.wait(100); }`
is there the same deadlock potential?

Comment: not the same, but another (if `t1` is started way before `t2`): `t1` could call `ada.notifyAll()` before `t2` calls `ada.wait()`. the problem is generally not easy to solve, and needs additional constructs.

Comment: It’s worth reading the API Note of [`wait(long timeoutMillis, int nanos)`’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,int)) In real applications, a thread doesn’t wait for another thread. A thread will wait for a certain *condition* which another thread may make true. As the documentation states, this condition should be checked with a loop within the `synchronized` block, to ensure not to miss if the condition is already fulfilled and to protect against spurious wakeups and other problematic scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

[The javadoc for Object.wait(...) methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,int)) advises this:

> The recommended approach to waiting is to check the condition being awaited in a while loop around the call to wait, as shown in the example below. Among other things, this approach avoids problems that can be caused by spurious wakeups.
>
> ```
>    synchronized (obj) {
>        while (<condition does not hold> and <timeout not exceeded>) {
>            long timeoutMillis = ... ; // recompute timeout values
>            int nanos = ... ;
>            obj.wait(timeoutMillis, nanos);
>        }
>        ... // Perform action appropriate to condition or timeout
>    }
> ```

So you can do something like this:

```
class MyThreads {
  final static Object lockObj = new Object();
  static int lineToPrint;
  
  static {
    synchronized (lockObj) {
      lineToPrint = 1;
    }
  }

  public static Thread t1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      waitThenPrintLine(1, "Thread 1 den");
      waitThenPrintLine(3, "Thread 1 ada");
    }
  };

  public static Thread t2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      waitThenPrintLine(2, "Thread 2 den");
      waitThenPrintLine(4, "Thread 2 ada");
    }
  };

  static void waitThenPrintLine(int lineNumber, String lineText) {
    try {
      synchronized (lockObj) {
        // wait for the given lineNumber
        while (lineToPrint != lineNumber) {
          lockObj.wait();
        }

        System.out.println(lineText);

        // increment lineToPrint and notify another thread about that
        lineToPrint++;
        lockObj.notify();
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  }
}
```